# Generate c# classes from json dynamically

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I usually use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate json classes to c#. But I do have problem. My json is have dynamic depth like this

```
    {
        "kategori": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "namakategori": "Tips &amp; Trick",
                "parent_id": "0",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "348",
                        "namakategori": "Fotografi",
                        "parent_id": "1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "370",
                        "namakategori": "Hacking",
                        "parent_id": "1",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
     {
                "id": "12",
                "namakategori": "Aplikasi",
                "parent_id": "0",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "13",
                        "namakategori": "Tools",
                        "parent_id": "12",
                        "children": [
                                     {
                                       "id": "14",
                                      "namakategori": "Toolsorder",
                                       "parent_id": "13",
                                       "children":[]
                                      },
                                     ]
                             },
                          ]
                       },
             ]
}
```

So how do I generate json classes dynamically so it can be used for my json? In above example I have 3 depth. But if I go to different page maybe it have 4 or more depth.

Comment: Shouldn't one class be enough? Something like `class jsonClass { int id { get; set; } string namakategori { get; set; } int parent_id { get; set; } List<jsonClass> children { get; set ; } jsonClass() { children = new List<jsonClass>(); } }`

Comment: What If I want to binding child only from that json? Or if I want to binding parent json only? From those class, I only can get child and parent become one class and I can't find how to distinct between parent and child data

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declere your classes *dynamically*. This should work:

```
public class Child
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string namakategori { get; set; }
    public string parent_id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> children { get; set; } // <-- See this
}

public class RootObj
{
    public List<Child> kategori { set; get; }
}
```

To deserialize I'll use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
 var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(json);
```

Comment: What If I want to binding child only from that json? Or if I want to binding parent json only? From those class, I only can get child and parent become one class and I can't find how to distinct between parent and child data

Comment: @blueboyz because there is no distinction. Every child is a parent of another child(s). Consider it like a *tree*. You should traverse your *tree*  to find the required node.

Comment: Any example code? maybe how I parse it. I still can't understand what you mean. What I need is to binding parent and child differently so I can display it inside listbox which have format parent and child differently

Comment: @blueboyz if you could do what you wanted, you wouldn't have asked that question. The answer is above. How to traverse a tree (using a stack or recursive functions) is a different question (and out of scope of this).

Comment: Can it be binded to listbox? I want later those class can be binded to listbox which have parent and child differently

Comment: @blueboyz You think (incorrectly) **X** is the way to solve your problem  and you ask about it. But the correct solution is **Y**.

Comment: So you think I need to ask new question or you can tell it the Y solution here?

Comment: @blueboyz This is a different question. Luckily for you, someone has asked this and got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682164/functionally-traversing-a-tree-in-c-sharp

Comment: Basically I still don't understand a lot about data structure in c# so I am little bit confused about tree. Could you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Newtonsoft.Json

For Instance,

```
JObject result = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonDataHere);
var katObject = result.Property("kategori").Value;
```

and so on...

PS: Not sure if Newtonsoft.Json is supported on WP7.